# Magento 1.3 requirements

Tags: php, migration, magento-1.3

I have an old website that runs magento 1.3 and i'm trying to move it to another server, but I can't find the system requirements of magento 1.3.

IT's currently using php 5.2, I'm wondering if it would work with magento 5.6?...

Comment: Do you a favor and try to update. I guess it takes longer to find a hoster that supports outdated PHP :)

Comment: @sv3n well we migrated to magento 2, but i need to keep the 1.3 online for now, until the magento 2 is ready to be online, will it work on php 5.5? Ty

Answer (score 1):

No. Magento 1.3 will not work with PHP 5.6. That version did not receive the PHP 5.6 or PHP 7.2 patches. I would recommend upgrading your site to Magento 1.9.3.10 if possible, or at least 1.7.0.2 if you can't do 1.9. You'll get security updates and some new features. Do not stick on 1.3 if it's possible. Your security will be minimal at best and you'll be easily compromised.

Comment: The site is likely already compromised

Comment: well we migrated to magento 2, but i need to keep the 1.3 online for now, until the magento 2 is ready to be online, will it work on php 5.5? Ty